# Show a Function is Strictly Convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I wish to show the function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = (1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is strictly convex. I am aware of the fact that $|x|^2$ is strictly convex and thus the shift $1 + |x|^2$ is strictly convex. However, I do not think the composition of a strictly convex function with $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is necessarily strictly convex. I also tried to show the Hessian matrix is positive definite, but the computation is intractable in $N$-dimension. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there are particular reason the question was down-voted? I will try and improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to restrict the answer (thanks to @Anne Bauval) to the so called strictly convex norms, which by definition satisfy
$$\left \|ax+(1-a)y)\right\|<a\|x|+(1-a)\|y\|,\quad x\neq y,\ \|x\|=\|y\|\neq 0,\ 0<a<1$$

For example the euclidean norm has that property, as well
as [(see)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573301/equivalence-of-strict-convexity-of-a-normed-space-with-strict-convexity-of-pth)$$\|x\|_p=\left (\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|^p\right )^{1/p},\ 1<p<\infty $$

For such norms we do not need to calculate the partial derivatives and  the $N$ dimensional Hessian, which can be unpleasent for some norms.

Assume the norm $g(x)=\|x|$ is strictly convex.  The function $h(t)=(1+t^2)^{1/2}$ is strictly increasing for $t\ge 0$ and  strictly convex as $$h''(t) =(1+t^2)^{-3/2}>0$$  Their composition $h(g(x))$ is thus strictly convex (verification at the end). Hence $f(x)$ is strictly convex because $$f(x)=(1+\|x\|^2)^{1/2}=h(g(x))$$

**Verification**
Consider nontrivial convex linear combination
$a,b>0,\ a+b=1$ and $x\neq y.$

1. $\|x\|\neq \|y\|.$

By the triangle inequality and homogeneity of the norm we have
$$g(ax+by) \leq ag(x)+bg(y)$$  and $g(x)\neq g(y).$ Therefore
$$h(g(ax+by))\le h(ag(x)+bg(y))\\ <ah(g(x))+bh(g(y))$$

2. $\|x\|=\|y\|$

Due to the strict convexity of the norm we have
$$g(ax+by)<ag(x)+bg(y)$$ and
$$h(g(ax+by))<h(ag(x)+bg(y))\le ah(g(x))+bh(g(x))$$

Comment: $x,y$ must be taken distinct but even so, the convexity of $g$ is not sufficient for your last inequality to be strict (think of $g=$ a constant function).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks !!. I have to restrict to strictly convex norms, as otherwise the conclusion fails.

Answer (score 4):

$$df_x(h)=\frac{x\cdot h}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}}$$

$$d^2f_x(h,k)=\frac{h\cdot k}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}}-\frac{(x\cdot h)(x\cdot k)}{(1+|x|^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$(1+|x|^2)^{3/2}d^2f_x(h,h)=|h|^2(1+|x|^2)-(x\cdot h)^2\ge|h|^2$$
(by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) hence $d^2f_x$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x, x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$.  Then by Cauchy-Schwarz on the two vectors $(1, x)$ and $(1, x_0)$ $$1 + \langle x, x_0 \rangle \leq (1+ \lVert x \rVert^2)^{\frac12} (1+ \lVert x_0 \rVert^2)^{\frac12}$$ with equality if and only if $x=x_0$. Rewrite this as $$f(x) \geq f(x_0) + \frac{\langle x-x_0, x_0 \rangle}{(1+\lVert x_0 \rVert^2)^{\frac12}}.$$  This shows that $f$ lies strictly above its tangent plane at $x_0$ for $x \neq x_0$.  This holds for any choice of $x_0$.  Therefore, $f$ is strictly convex.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your answer carefully. I delete my comment.